# getActivity() is null inside handler

Tags: android

I have an app with a single activity and two fragments. Fragment B is added(addedToBackStack) on Top of Fragment A. In Fragment B, I am showing a dialog, going back to Fragment A and then dismissing the dialog. If `getActivity()!=null` check is removed inside the handler, the code works fine. But `getActivity()` is null inside handler. Why is `getActivity()` null inside handler in the following piece of code?

```
 private void showDialog(final Dialog dialog) {
    dialog.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (getActivity()!=null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
    if (getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing())
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getActivity()` is null because after `getActivity().onBackPressed();` call your fragment will get detached from the `Activity`. So inside handler it will be always null because its getting called with a delay.
If you want to dismiss dialog after one second and also move back to previous fragment then you should move `onBackPressed` inside the run method. i have replaced the null check with `isAdded()`.

```
private void showDialog(final Dialog dialog) {
    dialog.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (isAdded()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: But how does the code work if getActivity() check is removed in my code? will the dialog hold an instance even after the fragment is destroyed?

Comment: [`isAdded()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#isAdded()) does same thing . It make sure that the Fragment is attached to the Activity if not then it will return false .